# Quick question: horizontal align taxonomy @ node/add?

Tags: nodes, entities

When adding a node (node/add/article), all the fields are showing up. With module "field group" i can alter the vertical presentation to an editor. In fact, the editor sees (for example) taxonomy-choices as:
Taxonomy
[] Tag 1
[] Tag 2
[] Tag 3
[] Tag 4
[] Tag 5

[] Option 1
[] Option 2
[] Option 3
[] Option 4
[] Option 5

[]Choise a
[]Choise b
[]Choise c
[]Choise d
[]Choise e

But how can i present it horizontal, like

Taxonomy-choices (here radiobuttons

+-----------+---------------+--------------+
| [] Tag 1  | [] Option 1 | []Choise a |
| [] Tag 2  | [] Option 2 | []Choise b |
| [] Tag 3  | [] Option 3 | []Choise c |
| [] Tag 4  | [] Option 4 | []Choise d |
| [] Tag 5  | [] Option 5 | []Choise e |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do that with pure CSS. In your example you would assign a float:left to your fieldgroups.

Comment: O man, that simple :-)
Thank you, that did the trick. I was searching in the modules & templates.